# Why is $\int_R f^{(p)}(x) g(x) d \gamma(x) = \int_R f^{(p-1)}(x) (xg(x) - g'(x)) d \gamma(x)$?

Tags: integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am self-studying *Normal approximations with Malliavin calculus* by Ivan Nourdin and Giovanni Peccati (btw I think the book is marvelous).

After having defined $\gamma$ as the standard Gaussian probability measure and having taken $f,g \in C^{\infty}$ Nourdin and Peccati state in Lemma 1.1.6 that

$$\int_R f^{(p)}(x) g(x) d \gamma(x) = \int_R f^{(p-1)}(x) (xg(x) - g'(x)) d \gamma(x)$$

this, they say, should follow from lemma 1.1.1 that says that letting $f: R \rightarrow R$ be an absolutely continuous function such that $f' \in L^1( \gamma)$. Then $x \rightarrow x f(x) \in L^1(\gamma)$ and
$$ \int_R x f(x) d \gamma(x) = \int_R f'(x) d \gamma(x)    $$.

I can't see why this would be, my calculations get me close but something is missing:

$$\int_R f^{(p)}(x) g(x) dx = g(x)f^{(p-1)}(x)   - \int_R f^{(p-1)}(x) g'(x) d x$$

and if $\int_R f^{(p-1)}(x) g'(x) d x = f^{(p-1)}(x) g'(x) /x$ I would be finished but this is not the case in general.

Comment: Apply the identity $$\int_\mathbb R xh(x)d\gamma(x)=\int_\mathbb R h'(x)d\gamma(x)$$ to the function $$h=f^{(p-1)}g$$ then reorder the terms, then rejoice

Comment: @Did Thanks! I am just a bit slow as usual.